# Ada2012: Assertion_Policy

Tags: ada, ada2012

According [Ada2012 RM Assertion_Policy](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-11-4-2.html):

> 10.2/3    A pragma Assertion_Policy applies to the named assertion aspects in a specific region, and applies to all assertion expressions
> specified in that region. **A pragma Assertion_Policy given in a**
> **declarative_part or immediately within a package_specification applies**
> **from the place of the pragma to the end of the innermost enclosing**
> **declarative region**. The region for a pragma Assertion_Policy given as
> a configuration pragma is the declarative region for the entire
> compilation unit (or units) to which it applies.

This means that if I have a package hierarchy as per the following example:

```
└───Root
    ├───Child1
    ├───Child2
    │   └───GrandSon
    └───Child3
```

And if I define the pragma Assertion_Policy at Root package specification, it will affect to the whole package hierarchy right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And if I define the pragma Assertion_Policy at Root package
> specification, it will affect to the whole package hierarchy right?

No.

What your bolded text means is that (a) the pragma is placed immediately in a specification, like so:

```
Pragme Ada_2012;                -- Placed "immediately".
Pragma Assertion_Policy(Check); -- Also "immediately".

Package Some_Spec is --... and so on.
```

or (b) in a declarative part:

```
Procedure Outer_Scope is
   Pragma Assertion_Polucy( Ignore ); -- Declarative region.
   X : Some_Type:= Possibly_Assertion_Failing_Operation;
   Package Inner_Scope is
    -- the stuff in here would ALSO ignore assertions.
   End Inner_Scope;
   Package Body Inner_Scope is Separate;
Begin
  if X'Valid then
    Null; -- Do things on the valid value of X.
  end if; -- Because we're ignoring the invalid case.
End Outer_Scope;
```

So, they apply not to children, but to the spec/body/declarative-region itself.

Comment: Wrong. A pragma in a pkg spec comes after `is`. A pragma before the `package P is` is a configuration pragma [ARM 10.1.5(8)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22aarm/html/AA-10-1-5.html#I5498).

Comment: Experimenting with GCC 13.1.0, `pragma Assertion_Policy (Check)` as a configuration pragma on a parent unit doesn’t have effect in a child unit. (I noticed [this hopeful statement](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22aarm/html/AA-11-4-2.html#p23.d)!)

Comment: Right, this is required by ARM 10.1.5. It's not clear to me if such a pragma in a pkg spec should also apply to child pkgs.